# No "Create Pull Request" option in Xcode 13.2.1

Tags: pull-request, xcode13, bitbucket-cloud

Having heard about the possibility to create and comment pull requests, I was about to try this feature:

- I have successfully added by Bitbucket Cloud account in Preferences using an App Password
- I can see my repository, branches
- I can create branches and view changes

However, nothing related to pull requests is available:

- Xcode does not detect pull requests
- I have no "Create Pull Request" option in Xcode
- I am using Xcode 13.2.1

Is there anything I have to set or enable for this feature to be available?

Thanks for any help in advance.